# excel: defining custom measures in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to define a custom measure in pivot table's aggregation.

Specifically, its the absolute value of the sum calculated by the pivot. 
The reason is , that the grand total column shows the "net" sum of other aggregated column measures; so if aggregated column A has +100, and column B has -100; the grand total nets to zero.

What I want is the aggregation calculating abs(+/- 100) = 100 for each column. This would cause the grand total to automatically report +200.

I've looked at Value Field Settings --> Show Values as option, but don't see a way of doing this

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel has ABS function to obtain the absolute value of a number.

Comment: how would you apply abs to the aggregated column values? Aggregation in pivot is done off the functions that are decided for you (such as sum, count etc)

Comment: in your intermediary steps, you can e.g. create a conditional abs if you have a negative value